# An issue with Content Hugging and Content Compression Resistance, Autolayout Constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I have modified the question to be more information provided and clear.

I wanted to have a dynamic table view cell, with a flexible height of UITextView and an optional UIImageView. Based on the content size of the UITextView and the optional UIImageView, the cell can be shrunk or extended.

**Here is what I expected to have (with the below picture):**

- Normal size: height of TextView is fixed (say 77). ImageView width and height are also fixed (say 130, 130)
- When content size of TextView decreasing, cell is shrunk and ImageView moves up.
- When there is no image in ImageView, the ImageView is not displaying, cell is shrunk.

[image]

**The below is the structure of views:**

- mainView is subview of contentView
- topView, textView, bigImageView, bottomView are subviews of mainView

[image]

**However, what I actually got is as follows.**

- Left picture: if the content size is large, then the ImageView cannot be seen.
- Right picture: If the content size is one line, the ImageView can be seen, but its width and height are not fixed 130, 130

[image]

**The warning issue is as follows:**

[image]

**If I fixed it by selecting "Add Missing Constraints", the result I got is as below:**

- Right picture showing that the height of TextView is not flexible anymore.

[image]

**TextView's constraints, Content Hugging Priority, Content Compression Resistance and Intrinsic Size:**

- I didn't use Intrinsic size for this TextView

[image]

**ImageView's constraints, Content Hugging Priority, Content Compression Resistance and Intrinsic Size:**

- I used Intrinsic size for this ImageView

[image]

I have been playing around with the Hugging Priority and Compression Resistance Priority for both TextView and ImageView but no luck. None of the results are what I expected.

Please help point out what is wrong in the settings and how to achieve my goal.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console about constraints not being satisfied? This layout should be ok as long as you have the image width/height fixed and the bottom of the image pinned to the outer view and the top pinned to the text area. If the blue area is a view inside the contentView, it needs pinned to the bottom of the contentView as well. Best to look at it in the preview panel to see how it will come out on screen. Your images seem to be from the storyboard?

Comment: Thanks Rory. I was in rush to ask the question, but now I reckon the information of my question is not so clear and confusing. I will modify it now.

Comment: Setting "Intrinsic Size" in IB never has any effect at run time. It's just a way to inform IB that a view will have an intrinsic size at run time so that it doesn't complain or do the wrong thing at design time. If what you tell IB about run time is wrong, then you'll get wrong results. In other words, you should almost never change that setting. If you want the image view to always size itself based on the image it's showing, set its hugging and compression resistance priorities to 1000. Similarly for the text view. Avoid setting explicit size constraints if possible.

Comment: I changed 'intrinsic size' back to default, and also set their hugging and compression resistance priorities to 1000, but it is still wrong. Did I have anything missing?

Comment: Which specific wrongness are you getting now?

Comment: Currently the main problem is roughly fixed by setting ImageView's height and width constraints <= 130. No more warning for hugging, compression resistance and intrinsic size by now. The whole part is a bit tricky and confusing for beginner. It is hard to explain. I need to get more familiar with constraints first. Thanks Ken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tricky part here would seem to be that when there is an image you want it to be 130x130 but when there is no image you want it to be hidden.

My suggestion would be to add a constraint for the height and width which is <= 130 rather than = 130 and to add a constraint for the aspect ratio which is 1:1.

This will allow the image view to shrink to 0x0 when there is no image.

When there is an image it will scale to the image size, but stay square. It will never go larger than 130x130. Not quite what you wanted but close.

You should not need to worry about hugging and compression I do not think.

To do exactly what you want I think requires code. You need to create IBOutlets for the height and width constraints but this time make them =130. In your code when you set the image into the image view, set the constraint constants in code to either 130 or 0. This I think is the only way to achieve exactly what you are asking for. To do this you CTRL drag from your width and height constraints into the .h for the controller and create the IBOutlets. This is how I deal with constraints which require a decision based on the state of the data model for cells.

Comment: ImageView Height & width <= 130 is exactly what I did and it fixed the tricky part. I also changed TextView height <= 77. As you suggested before, I'm not worrying about hugging and compression in current situation anymore. I changed them back to default setting. Regarding IBOutlet of height/width constraint in code, I did try it before for TextView height constraint and I guess I didn't do it correctly so I got wrong result. Currently my main problem is fixed, but something still needs to be adjusted slightly. I'll try IBOutlets for height and width constraints again. Thank you Rory.

Comment: Glad it worked. You will notice a difference I think on different phone types due to the difference in resolutions. For retina you will want images at least 260x260 pixels to force it to 130x130 pts. On iPhone 6+ You will need 390x390 pixels. Only way to deal with that is the IBOutlet method as that sets the points x points.